# Python Discord private message without another user

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```py
await self.client.get_user(user id).send(msg)
```

when i put a user id for one of my account it worked
but when i used my friend it says `AttributeError`

```py
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

the bot need to message the other person(the user id) in private

```py
@client.command()
async def DM(ctx,  message): 
userid = 'stored here
await self.client.get_user(user id).send(msg)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  This should at least include the command in question and the code that inserts data into the database. It would also help to know the schema of the table, especially the data type of the user id field.

Comment: im new to stack overflow

Comment: Is `userid` a string in your real code?  It needs to be an integer.

Comment: its an integer, the issue is that for a specific account it works, while it doesnt not for another

Comment: Can you modify this so it gets the userid separately and prints `repr(userid)`?  `get_user` can't find anyone with that id, which usually means there's something wrong with it

Comment: wdym separately so like... c = client.get_user and then await c.send(msg)?

Comment: just print `repr(userid)` before calling `get_user`

Comment: still same error await client.get_user(repr(442489216176278720)).send("ERROR budget")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Comment: Solved my db was storing wrong user id and so thats why

Answer (score 0):

You might have the wrong id.  Try something like

```
@bot.command()
async def get_id(ctx, *, user: discord.User):
    await ctx.send(str(user.id))
```

to get the correct id.  You would call this like `!get_id @MyFriend`

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to send a message to the user this might help

```
@bot.command()
async def dm(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, message)
    await member.send(message)
```

Comment: i was not trying to mention the reciever, anyways got the code

Comment: ```python await self.client.get_user(userid).send("ERROR budget")``` This works it was not with the discord.py 's problem my db was rounding the userid when stored hence wrong user id